# How have I earned 7 “Yearling” badges in the last 4 years?

Tags: bug, badges

I made my account on this site about 7.5 years ago, but my first rep-earning activity (aside from association bonus) was in October of 2021. How then, have I managed to get 7 copies of the “Yearling” badge in that time, which reads:

> Active member for a year, earning at least 200 reputation. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

You can [see here](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/badges/13/yearling?userid=16533) that I’ve managed to get the badge twice in a year, multiple times. In fact, I got it twice in a 3 day span in 2021, after already having received it once earlier that year. Is this a bug, a feature, some weird quirk of Stack Exchange, or am I fundamentally misunderstanding how the badge is supposed to be awarded?

My best guess: since I had an account but was not earning rep, it’s basically giving me a yearling badge every 200 rep, up to however many years my account has existed, *without* checking whether one has been earned that year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They see how long you have, and how much reputation you have. It doesn't care that the reputation wasn't earned early on. You are pretty much spot on.